# VB.Net Print with Excel Template Quickly

Tags: excel, vb.net, winforms

I am working on VB.Net ERP application, which is used for modification of Customer, Product, Stock details and Billing the product.

To print a bill, I have used predefined excel template. Upon clicking Print button, it will just open the excel and pass the values using Excel object, after that it will print the active sheet from the application background,which used don't know the process. I am facing slowness while printing, It takes around 1 or 2 minutes to complete the entire print operation. I am using below code:

```
Private Function WriteDetailsInfileDOS(BillNumber As String, BillType As String, PrintCopy As Integer) As Boolean
        'Define your Excel Objects
        Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
        Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

        Try
            Select Case BillType
                'Opens Source Workbook. Change path and filename as applicable
                Case "KAS"
                    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Replace("\bin\Debug", "") + "Templates\S_Invoice_Template.xlsx")
                    'Select a worksheet
                    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("S_Invoice_Template")
                    Exit Select
                Case "SVC"
                    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Replace("\bin\Debug", "") + "Templates\V_Invoice_Template.xlsx")
                    'Select a worksheet
                    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("V_Invoice_Template")
                    Exit Select
                Case "CHERAN"
                    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Replace("\bin\Debug", "") + "Templates\C_Invoice_Template.xlsx")
                    'Select a worksheet
                    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("C_Invoice_Template")
                    Exit Select
                Case "ESTIMATE"
                    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Replace("\bin\Debug", "") + "Templates\ESTIMATE_Template.xlsx")
                    'Select a worksheet
                    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("ESTIMATE_Template")
                    Exit Select
                Case Else
                    Return False
            End Select

            'Display Excel
            xlApp.Visible = False
            xlApp.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False

            xlWorkSheet.Cells(6, 9).value = BillNumber
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(8, 7).value = lblC_Code.Text

            xlWorkSheet.Cells(11, 4).value = txtCName.Text
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(12, 4).value = txtCAddress.Text
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(13, 4).value = txtCCity.Text
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(14, 4).value = txtCPincode.Text
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(15, 4).value = txtCPhone.Text
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(13, 7).value = txtCTIN.Text

            xlWorkSheet.Cells(10, 9).value = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(11, 9).value = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek.ToString()
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(12, 9).value = UserName.ToString()
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(14, 9).value = txtTotal.Text
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(34, 8).value = txtTotal.Text
            Dim RowCount As Integer = gvBill.RowCount
            Dim S As Integer = 0
            Dim BillDescCell As Integer = 17

            For Each Row As DataGridViewRow In Me.gvBill.Rows
                If BillDescCell = 33 Then
                    Exit For
                End If
                S = S + 1
                If Row.Cells(Me.Product.Index).Value <> "" Then
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells(BillDescCell, 3).value = S.ToString()
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells(BillDescCell, 4).value = Row.Cells(Me.Product.Index).Value.ToString
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells(BillDescCell, 6).value = Row.Cells(Me.Qty.Index).Value.ToString
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells(BillDescCell, 7).value = Row.Cells(Me.Unit.Index).Value.ToString
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells(BillDescCell, 8).value = Row.Cells(Me.Rate.Index).Value.ToString
                End If
                BillDescCell = BillDescCell + 1
            Next

            ' Printing the Excel Workbook
            xlWorkSheet.PrintOut(From:=1, To:=1, Copies:=PrintCopy, Collate:=True)
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            ExceptionLog(Me.GetType.Name.ToString, "WriteDetailsInfileDOS", ex.ToString().ToString, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"))
            Return False
        Finally
            ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet)
            ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook)
            ReleaseComObject(xlApp)
        End Try
    End Function
```

I am thinking this slowness is because of opening the excel at each print click. I think, we can open the Excel, while application startup itself so that, On clicking print button, it will just pass the value and print excel within few seconds. I know creating variable globally but I don't know how to write method globally and using the excel objects globally to pass the values.

Update:
I have created module and having the excel open code in that module method. I just called the method from application startup event.

Will it be good?

Comment: Do you really need Excel for printing ? Have you consider using some reporting solution like the report control, Crystal report or other third party tool ?

Comment: @MarcoGuignard We are having some templates that needs to be print also, That is why i am preferring excel.

Comment: You could use a class with shared method and properties to handle this stuff or a module if you use VB.NET (it's the same concept behind, just an old vb syntax).

Comment: @MarcoGuignard, Could you please share me the code.

Comment: If you don't know of to use shared concept/keyword as global variable, better have to read the doc first. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2b427x.aspx . I don't have a sample on hand of using Office automation like this.